# How to Add 10mins to a datetime in python

Tags: python, time

```
cdr_start_time = "12:10:13"
start_time = "00:10:00"

if cdr_start_time > start_time:
    start_time = start_time + 10
```

In the above code I would like to add 10mins after time comparison, how do I do in python.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
import datetime
cdr_start_time = "12:10:13"
start_time = "00:10:00"
mydate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(cdr_start_time, '%H:%M:%S') # Creates a datetime object
mydate2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M:%S')
if mydate1 > mydate2:
    mydate2 += datetime.timedelta(minutes=10) # Adds ten minutes to the datetime object

print datetime.datetime.strftime(mydate2, '%H:%M:%S') # Turns it back to a readable string
```

Prints:

```
00:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

```
from datetime import datetme,timedelta
>>> d = datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 25, 12, 23, 14, 410952)

>>> d1 = d+timedelta(minutes=20)
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 25, 12, 23, 14, 410952)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` you can do this with the `Timestamp` class, which is a subclass of `datetime.datetime`:

```
In [63]: from pandas import Timestamp

In [64]: from pandas.offsets import Minute, date_range

In [65]: pd.Timestamp('1/1/2001') + Minute(10)
Out[65]: Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:10:00', tz=None)
```

This extends to arrays of `datetime64`s too:

```
In [66]: date_range('1/1/2001', periods=10).to_series() + Minute(10)

Out[66]:
2001-01-01   2001-01-01 00:10:00
2001-01-02   2001-01-02 00:10:00
2001-01-03   2001-01-03 00:10:00
2001-01-04   2001-01-04 00:10:00
2001-01-05   2001-01-05 00:10:00
2001-01-06   2001-01-06 00:10:00
2001-01-07   2001-01-07 00:10:00
2001-01-08   2001-01-08 00:10:00
2001-01-09   2001-01-09 00:10:00
2001-01-10   2001-01-10 00:10:00
Freq: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```